# Add multiple Hyperlinks to PowerPoint Shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

**Task:** I have a PowerPoint file which contains slides with text in them. The text contains codewords, that I want to replace with a hyperlink. Right now I am using the code below to achieve this.

```
For Each sld In prt.Slides
  For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
      If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then

        Set rngToSearch = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
        Set rngFound = rngToSearch.Find("SomeLink")

        Do While Not (rngFound Is Nothing)
            With rngFound

                With .ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
                    .Action = ppActionHyperlink
                    .Hyperlink.Address = "http://www.SomeLink.de"
                    .Hyperlink.TextToDisplay = "SomeLink"
                End With

                .Font.Bold = msoFalse

                Set rngFound = rngToSearch.Find("SomeLink", .Start + .Length - 1)

            End With
        Loop

      End If
    End If
  Next shp
Next sld
```

**What works:** The code manages to find all the occurences of the codeword *SomeLink* and it makes every occurence of this word bold (which I just do for testing purposes). This tells me, that the variable *rngFound* works correctly (i.e. is set to the right subparts of the text of every TextFrame.

**What doesn't work:** Instead of creating a hyperlink for every codeword in the shape, the code only takes the first word of every shape where a codeword is found and creates the hyperlink. The pictures below show a before and after to make this clearer.

**Before:**

[image: A slide before the code was executed]

**After:**

[image: The same slide after the code was executed]

**Question:** Does anybody know how to make this code run how it's supposed to? I am literally freaking out right now.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it, but I think this is interesting so I will not just delete the question but actually give an answer. So the code below did the trick.

```
For Each sld In prt.Slides
  For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
      If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then

        Set rngToSearch = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
        Set rngFound = rngToSearch.Find("SomeLink")

        Do While Not (rngFound Is Nothing)
            With rngFound

                rngFound.Text = "SomeLink"

                With .ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
                    .Action = ppActionHyperlink
                    .Hyperlink.Address = "http://www.SomeLink.de"
                End With

                Set rngFound = rngToSearch.Find("SomeLink", .Start + .Length - 1)

            End With
        Loop

      End If
    End If
  Next shp
Next sld
```

What did I change? Well, basically only two lines! My mistake was the line `.Hyperlink.TextToDisplay = "SomeLink"`. This somehow messed with the Textrange. Instead I now first change the text of the found Textrange with the new line `rngFound.Text = "SomeLink"` and then create the hyperlink.